# invalid initialization of non-const reference to global variable

Tags: c++, reference, global-variables, rvalue

I am using a function from a library of the form:

```
void run(double in, double &out);
```

I cannot change this function, and I need to pass "out" to many different functions in different classes. Since I need to access it throughout the program, often when it is not convenient to create a class instance, I would like to pass a global double in for "out." However, when I try the following,

```
#include <iostream>

double inputDouble = 3;
double outputDouble;

void run(double in, double &out)
{
    out = in + 5;
}

int main()
{
    run(inputDouble, &outputDouble);
    std::cout << outputDouble << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘double&’ from an rvalue of type ‘double*’
```

I'm a little shaky on references, pointers, and lvalue/rvalues, so please give me a simple answer of why I can't do this, and how I can accomplish my goal of assigning value to "out" and using it throughout the program.

Comment: I recommend avoiding "out parameters" and instead use the return value.  They're both idiomatic C++, but the return value reads much better (i.e., easier maintenance).  `double run(double in) { return in + 5; }` and `outputDouble = run(inputDouble);`

Comment: @Eljay notice in the first sentence, I say I am using a function from a library I cannot change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `main` you are calling `run` with the second parameter being a *pointer* to double. The `&` operator in this case takes the address of `outputDouble`, it does not make a reference.

Remove the `&` on the call and a reference will be passed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer, but it works.